# Java Executor right way?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I've got some issue with executors. Is this the right way to use them?
Everything works fine for couple of hours since program execution, but then I assume threads start to behave a bit strange ...

VPNConnect thread is used to restart the vpn connection at each odd, full hour. The thread checks in the loop what time it is and when the time comes, sets flag 1 in its place on the database.

The other two independent threads do something different in the loops, while checking the flag set by the vpn thread. If the flag has been changed to 1, each thread allows the current loop to end and does not start another one. After finishing the last loop, the Rzeszowiak and NieruchomiamiGdynia thread set their flags to 0.

And now, if both of the above flags are set to 0 and the vpn flag is equal to 1, vpn is disconnected and reconnected, then the vpn thread sets its flag to 0. Threads Rzeszowiak i NieruchomosciGdynia seeing that the thread vpn has the flag 0 arouse work setting its flags on 1.

For the next 2 hours, the Rzeszowiak and NieruchomosciGdynia threads do their job while the vpn thread is set to 0. When the full, odd hour comes, the vpn thread sets its flag to 1 and the game starts again, as I described above.

So what's the problem?

For a short time after starting the program everything works as it should. For example, about 23:00 two threads finish their work, wait for the vpn restart and again arouse to work until 01:00 and then again restart vpn work until 03:00, reboot, etc ... At least it should be theory ...

Practice, however, shows that after a few (sometimes 3, sometimes 4, sometimes 6 - there is no rule) comes to the following situations:

1. The vpn thread does not disconnect and reconnect, although Rzeszowiak and NieruchomieniaGdynia are waiting for it (0 set on the basis).
2. The vpn thread disconnects and reconnects, but the Rzeszowiak and NieruchomiamiGdynia threads do not arouse.

I have a strange feeling that after some time these threads are lost somewhere or even disappear. Everything returns to order when I stop the entire program and run it again (without any manual interference in the state of the database). The situation is ok sometimes for 3 hours, sometimes 6 and sometimes even for a day ...

```
    ConfigFile cf = new ConfigFile(args[0], args[1]);
    cf.loadFile();

    VPNConnect vpnConnectThread  = new VPNConnect();
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(vpnConnectThread,1,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

if(cf.getRzeszowiak()!=null && !cf.getRzeszowiak().equals("")) {
        RzeszowiakPl rzeszowiakPlThread  = new RzeszowiakPl(cf.getRzeszowiak());
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(rzeszowiakPlThread,1,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);}

if(cf.getNieruchomsciGdynia()!=null && !cf.getNieruchomsciGdynia().equals("")) {
        NieruchomosciGdynia nieruchomosciGdyniaThread  = new NieruchomosciGdynia(cf.getNieruchomsciGdynia());
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(nieruchomosciGdyniaThread,1,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `threads start to behave a bit strange`?

Comment: I second Ivan, what exactly is the problem? You need to tell us _what you expect to be happening_ and _what is actually happening_ (read [ask]). Simply putting up code and hoping someone has an epiphany is not productive.

Comment: @Ivan, I've just updated the entire post. Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you declare flag variables? Do you use `volatile` or `AtomicBoolean`? have you tried additional logs?

Comment: @Slaw, I've just described what the problem is. Hope you could help.

Comment: Have you tried attaching with a remote debugger and seeing if the threads are still running?  In Eclipse IDE it is easy to stop individual threads(easier if the threads have names) and see where the thread is as far as execution.

Comment: It's possible that the `ScheduledExecutorService` is being GC'd. Looking at the source code `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` returns a delegate around a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which extends from `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The class `ThreadPoolExecutor` extends `Object.finalize()` and calls `shutdown()` on itself when being GC'd. Since by default a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` _does not_ continue executing periodic tasks upon shutdown it is possible the pool, along with the `Thread`s, are being GC'd. As _ProgrammersBlock_ suggests, you could watch the app from a debugger.

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to store each `ScheduledExecutorService` in a variable that remains strongly referenced for the duration of the application's life (btw, why don't you just create _one_ `ScheduledExecutorService` with a fixed size of 3?). The other possible problem is hinted at by _Ivan_: it could be a synchronization issue. Are you sure the other threads are seeing the updates to the flag? Are there race conditions (causing deadlock)? Also, instead of polling you may want to look into blocking strategies (using things like `Lock`s/`Condition`s or `Object.wait`/`Object.notify`).

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock, I've just found out where to track it in IntelliJ. I see my threads in two states: **RUNNING** or **SLEEPING**. Additional threads I can see are: _DestroyJavaVM_, _Finalizer_, _**Keep-Alive-Timer**_ (it shows for a moment and disappears), _Reference Handler_, _Signal Dispatcher_

Comment: @Slaw, what does it mean, `ScheduledExecutorService` is being GC'd?

Comment: "GC'd" is shorthand for "garbage collected".

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock, in IntelliJ threads debugger I can see threads are still running, but they're not really working (they should at least sysout logs, but they don't event do these) ... Or my logback.xml is written badly and doesn't catch this messages ...

Comment: Do you mean to say that the threads still exist or that the threads have gone into the run state without going into the sleeping state?  According to Javadoc of ScheduleWithFixedDelay, the previous execution must terminate before the next thread can be scheduled.  Are you able to pause the thread in the debugger to see if it might be stuck on anything?

Comment: I'm saying that it happens to see the thread mode in the RUNNING state however I can't see any thread work (no INFO nor DEBUG logs on the output)... I'm able to pause the thread in the debugger mode.

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock, maybe it's due to logback.xml current configuration, I can't see some output?